# Crackling, poor and low sound on HP Envy x360 AMD (Bang&Olufsen) and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound

I have a problem with my HP Envy x360 and Ryzen 5. It has Bang & Olufsen speakers. I also tried connecting Bluetooth Headphones (Niceboy Hive 2). Status:

- sound works
- sound is very low, and low in quality (very flat sounding)
- mic seems to work as per test in the settings
- when using overamplification, the anyway poor sound just starts crackling and is distorted

Did anyone get this to work, or is it a nyet? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do anymore. Point release fixed it last fall.

Comment: if you accept your own answer we can avoid this question popping up in the future :)